# PIC24F issues reading analog AC microphone values

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab, adc

I am using a PIC24FJ128GA010 to read the microphone values. When I read the raw values from the sensor I am getting like 270 but over time the value will go down to 90 and stop. 3.3V is being used and when noise is made the values will change even when its slowly going down to 90. I am not sure why this is the case. I just have 3.3V, ground and an analog input pin connected to the microphone. The microphone I believe picks up noise from -1.7V to 1.7V.

I am setting AD1CON2 = 0x0000; where AVss and AVdd is used as Vref.

Is there a way I can fix the readings from the microphone to display 90 right away? I know that 90 represents 0 and probably will need to fix that so the values would be read just on the positive side. Would using a capacitor help fix this issue?

I am very new to programming microcontrollers and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have proper AC coupling between the microphone and the input to the ADC?  You need proper AC coupling and DC offset, as you would for any transistor or opamp.

Comment: @MichaelRoy The mic has a built in capacitor that is in series with AC pin that is 10uF Would I still then need additional components?

Comment: Well, yes.  The ADC cannot read voltages below 0V. You must offset the AC signal from the microphone  to something usable, like 1.8V.  ADC's input impedance are in the 10K range,  What is the output impedance of you micrphone ?  If it's anything over 10K, you'll need some kind of preamp.  Either a transistor (that's the cheapest, but requires more maths) or an opamp (cheap and easy to make, if you have one on hand).  These are quite easy and cheap to implemennt.

Comment: The actual circuit depends on the type of microphone you have...  Which is?

Comment: The microphone is Adafruit MEMS mic SPW2430

Comment: That should work.  Connect to the DC pin.  You should get ADC readings around 850, range of readings should  be around +- 400 above and below 850.

Comment: I connected to the DC pin and the ADC readings I am getting are around 245 and range of readings go above and below it

Comment: Looks like it's working.  Don't expect full range without a preamp, as explained on the adafruit site.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, will an amplifier work or is the preamp the only way? Also how did you get 850? Is that the amplitude?

Comment: A preamp is an amplifier.  I got the 850 from the Adafruit website, it advertize a 0.67V  DC offset. which is about 850 on a 12 bit ADC @3.3V....

Comment: Okay thank you, I will try to get an amp/make one. Are there any good articles/tutorials or links to information about making an amp/preamp? Thanks

Comment: Yes, look towards the Arduino community for more info.  You can probably find more preamps than you want to look at with a duck duck go search, ranging from very simple to very complex.

Comment: The amp that we are using is a rail to rail non inverting amp TLV2462 and are using a 11.9k connected to GND, and 46.6k is connected between negative input of amp and output of amp. The value we are getting now is 330 but it slowly goes down. We are using 10 bit ADC so the values we should be getting ideally with an amp should be lower than 850.

Comment: With only 2 resistors, I can only assume the DC offset (voltage on the negative input) of your op amp is 0V...  Your op amp is slowly draining tthe output capacitor of the mic, to eventually settle at 0V, which is not what you want.  You must bias the negative input of the opamp to something usefull, something closer to 1.8V, so your output voltage (and DC bias on your positive output) is already close to 1.8V when the mic is not connected.